# ScaleBar in pyqtgraph doesn't update when scale is changed

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

When I change the scale of the axis of my image, my ScaleBar shows the incorrect scale. How do I update the scale bar when I change the axes?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    imvOCTTopLeft = pg.ImageView(view=pg.PlotItem())
    imvOCTTopLeft.setImage(np.random.normal(size=(100,100)))

    imvOCTTopLeft.view.getAxis('left').setScale(0.6)
    imvOCTTopLeft.view.getAxis('bottom').setScale(0.4)

    scale = pg.ScaleBar(size=10,suffix = "px")
    viewbox = imvOCTTopLeft.view
    if not isinstance(viewbox, pg.ViewBox): viewbox = viewbox.getViewBox()
    scale.setParentItem(viewbox)
    scale.anchor((1, 1), (1, 1), offset=(-20, -20))
    imvOCTTopLeft.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This image shows that the scale bar is showing approximately 4 pixels but states that it is showing 10 pixels.

[image]

I think this is because I changed the axis scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug: [link](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/437). The viewbox rescales after `sigRangeChanged` is emitted.

"Hacky" solution is to delay the `ScaleBar` update: 
(You might need to play around with the `time`, `100` and `10` worked for me. If it doesnt work, increase it.)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


def updateDelay(scale, time):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(time, scale.updateBar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    plotItem = pg.PlotItem()
    imvOCTTopLeft = pg.ImageView(view=plotItem)
    imvOCTTopLeft.setImage(np.random.normal(size=(100, 100)))

    imvOCTTopLeft.view.getAxis('left').setScale(0.6)
    scale = 0.4 #edit
    imvOCTTopLeft.view.getAxis('bottom').setScale(scale) #edit

    scale = pg.ScaleBar(size=10*(1/scale), suffix="px") #edit
    scale.text.setText('10 px') #edit
    plotItem.sigRangeChanged.connect(lambda: updateDelay(scale, 10))  # here: time=10ms
    viewbox = imvOCTTopLeft.view
    if not isinstance(viewbox, pg.ViewBox): viewbox = viewbox.getViewBox()
    scale.setParentItem(viewbox)
    scale.anchor((1, 1), (1, 1), offset=(-20, -20))
    imvOCTTopLeft.show()
    updateDelay(scale, 100)  # here time=100ms

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, That helped with the problem of my scale bar not updating however the scale bar is still not showing the correct scale when I change the axis scale.

Comment: Do you mean when you call `plotItem.setXRange(x1, x2)`? You also have to call `updateDelay(scale, 100)` after that.

Comment: I'm not sure. Please see my recent edit where I have attached a photo of my problem. Hopefully this will explain my problem better.

Comment: @jadem see my edit (the 4 lines i marked with `#edit`)